# Comparison of the date in oracle sqlplus

Tags: sql, oracle, join

```
SET TERMOUT ON

DROP VIEW BP_VIEW;  
CREATE VIEW BP_VIEW AS
SELECT b.BOOKINGID, 
       g.GUESTID,   
       g.FORENAME, g.SURNAME, 
       br.FLOORNO, br.ROOMNO, 
       r.TYPE, 
       b.TOTALPRICE + (rt.RATE*(b.DEPARTDATE - b.ARRIVEDATE)) AS TOTAL_AMOUNT_DUE
FROM   GUEST g, ROOM r
INNER JOIN BOOKING b ON b.BOOKINGID = GUESTID
INNER JOIN BOOKINGROOM br ON b.BOOKINGID = br.BOOKINGID AND r.FLOORNO = br.FLOORNO AND r.ROOMNO = br.ROOMNO
INNER JOIN ROOMTYPE rt ON rt.TYPE = r.TYPE
WHERE (CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN b.ARRIVEDATE AND b.DEPARTDATE);

SELECT * FROM BP_VIEW;

COMMIT;

SET TERMOUT ON
```

Hello Guys,

I am trying to execute the above code and it executes fine but it is picking update certain bookings which do not fall into the category of CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN b.ARRIVEDATE AND b.DEPARTDATE.

With this statement I am trying to find booking information which are current and not past bookings.

While the code executes, the results are not what I expect. Have I done the AND SECTION CORRECTLY?

Comment: What datatypes are `ARRIVEDATE` and `DEPARTDATE`?

Comment: Not sure if it will resolve, but `ROOM` and `ROOMTYPE` are joined together, but not to any other table. Seems like you are missing a join between `BOOKINGROOM` and `ROOM`

Comment: @JWK - Nice catch. It shows that's it's far better to write explicit joins instead of holding on to this implicit join syntax.

Comment: that didnt resolve the problem see my edit

Comment: @MuminAli your edit is invalid as you've mixed ANSI and non ANSI. remove the `, ROOM r, BOOKING b, BOOKINGROOM br, ROOMTYPE rt` part totally and join ROOM with ANSI.

Comment: @DazzaL changed what you said, executes but still the date issue. picking booking which do no fall in the where condition

Comment: @MuminAli - no you didn't. You are still left with `GUEST g, ROOM r`. Write these as *proper* joins.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle's date datatype includes the time.  That means this:

```
where datefield between date1 and date2
```

usually misses record that happened on date2.  This is better:

```
where datefield >= date1
and datefield < date2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding a trunc() to both sides to remove time portion from dates unless you want to compare date and time. Also, BETWEEN operator can be used and more readable...T:

```
WHERE trunc(CURRENT_DATE) >= trunc(b.ARRIVEDATE) AND trunc(CURRENT_DATE) <= trunc(b.DEPARTDATE)
```

Comment: @Mumin Ali-this most likely means you have no data between those dates. Add sample data, e.g. tables, rows... to your post. Make sure your dates exist in your table - make it simple, select from a single table with dates first to be sure you have correct data and dates then add other tables... There is no way to test your query w/out sample data.